# Want to set Font of document (.doc) in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Hi I am using following code in the MAC application for setting font of document file. But I didn't get any success to set font in iOS application.

```
NSFont *docFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:12];
NSDictionary *docAttributes =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: docFont,NSFontAttributeName,nil];
NSAttributedString *docAttributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:doc attributes:gradeDocAttributes];

NSData *docData = [docAttributed docFormatFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [gradeDoc length]) documentAttributes:nil];

    // write docData to a file
[docData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

how can I implement same functionality in iOS application.

I am able to write file. following code I used for write file in my iOS app. But no success for setting font of it.

```
NSString *doc=[self calculatedResult];
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* path;
NSString* str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.objStudent.name];
str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@".doc"];
path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
[doc writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `docFormatFromRange:documentAttributes:` is defined in "NSAttributedString *Application Kit* Additions" (as found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html).

It's only available on AppKit (OS X) but not in the Core Text implementation of iOS. So there is no way to create a `.doc` file on iOS.

Comment: Christian Beer, I also added my code for creating (.doc) file in post .. you can check that.

Comment: @user606348: No, you didn't. You added some code that writes out a text file (possibly a garbage one, depending on whether the string returned by `calculatedResult` really is plain text). You didn't show any code that generates Word data to write to a Word document file. I can assume that `calculatedResult` is supposed to generate the Word data, but it returns the wrong type—a Word file is not plain text, so it should return an NSData object (just like AppKit's `docFormatFromRange:…:` method does), not a string. At any rate, you didn't show how `calculatedResult` generates a Word document.

Comment: @user606348: "I also added my code for creating (.doc) file in post". As Peter said you only added code that shows how you write a (text) file. If you use a Mac that gets opened without problems in TextEdit (as do .doc files that are _true_ Word files) but doesn't have any formatting.

You will _not_ be able to create a real Word file on iOS. What you can do is create PDF files, though.

Answer (score 1):

As per doc

> NSFont - Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.

Use Core Text insted:

> Core Text is an advanced, low-level technology for laying out text and
>   handling fonts. It is designed for high performance and ease of use.
>   The Core Text API, introduced in Mac OS X v10.5, is accessible from
>   all Mac OS X application environments. It is also available in iOS
>   3.2.

For instance use [CTFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html) instead of NSFont

For the core text guide go [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Cyprian, I know NSFont is use in MAC application and UIFont in iOS.And also Core Text API working well in my mac application, but not working in iOS. Hopefully sdk 5.0 not the reason of it.

Comment: @user606348: How is it “not working”? This sort of information should be in your question, and you should be very specific about exactly what you tried—including what you did with CTFont—and how it didn't work.

Comment: @Peter Hosey CTFont is working.. I able get NSMutableAttributedString 
But when I try to use following code
`[attrString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];`. application crashed..
then I just make NSMutableAttributedString to string and then its write method. It able to create file but with garbage content.

So @Peter Hosey, let's back main problem. Is there any way to create word file in ios? and setting its attributes etc.